# Whatsapp is behaving weird

Tags: apps, whatsapp

My whatsapp is behaving kinda weird...it was all ok this morning suddenly I am receiving the same message every now and then from my friend which he had sent long back and I also replied back to him (though he has not yet received my replies). every 2-3 minutes the same message keeps poping and I really don't know why. I tried to turn off the phone but it didn't help.
Has anyone of you recognized such problem and has a solution to it?

Ill be really glad if you help me out with this!

Thanks a ton!!

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling WhatsApp?

Comment: I had never heard about this problem. But I encourage you to uninstall and install again too.

Comment: Hey guys thanks a ton for your help, my whatsapp is now working well...Thanks again!

Comment: @akid maybe add you comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Turning your phone off and on again is always a good start. If that doesn't help, removing and reinstalling the offending app is the next thing I'd do.